# Problems installing Glew on mac

Tags: xcode, opengl, osx-lion, homebrew, glew

I am having trouble installing Glew on my Mac. I've installed it using HomeBrew and it appears to be installed correctly.

However I can't `#include` the *glew.h* files or add any of the Glew frameworks.

Most of the suggested solutions to this that I've found appear to be out of date. E.g. [this link](http://julovi.net/j/?p=21) - step 5 Add > existing frameworks isn't in newer Xcodes so I cant navigate to the */usr/* folder.

Anyone else with this problem?

Update #1: This new problem of "undefined for architecture.." clearly is derived from Xcode not being able to find the frameworks, I installed Glew using HomeBrew which means that the frame works are in */usr/local/cellar/glew/1.9/lib* is this the correct path? I have the framework search paths set to */usr/local/cellar/***, any suggestions?

Comment: "*However I can't #include the glew.h files or add any of the Glew frameworks.*" What do you mean by "can't"? What happens when you try?

Comment: I managed to fix the #include issue (set all search paths to /usr/local/cellar/**) what i meant was i was getting an error for #include and i couldn't find any glew related frameworks, still have that problem. I think "not found for architecture..." errors are related to frameworks not been added right? Still new to Xcode!

Comment: Also worth adding that this problem, "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:", is also occurring with SDL and presumably anything I install via HomeBrew.

Answer (score 0):

For GLEW to work properly,
In the build settings of your project, change the Base SDK to Current OS X, and add the entry "-lGLEW" to your other linker flags section.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps you now but i had the same problem.

after installing glew with homebrew I included the header file

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

in my main.cpp

after that, in the proyect configuration -> build settings -> search paths -> library search paths 
i added this path: /usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.11.0/lib

and in the same page, linking->other linking flags 
i put the flag "-lGLEW"

then, i ran my project with a line `glewInit();` and everything worked well .

hope that it helps you after so long.

cheers!